# Custom Report not displaying records

Tags: reporting, opportunity, custom-report-type

My custom object Quotation have lookup with Opportunity. Another custom object Quotation Line Item have lookup with Opportunity. Now i created record on Opportunity, under this Opportunity Quotation created. Under this Quotation, Quotation Line Item record created.

I am created custom report type Opportunity with Quotations with Quotation Line Item. When i run the report i didn't see any records under my report. I am the Admin and the report hierarchy is mine. There is no filters in the report.

May i know whats the reason to not showing any records.

Below is the my screen shot. 
[image]

Comment: Do you own the records as well, Can you check what is the sharing settings set for these objects?Are you the 'CEO'?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo, just now i checked it. There lot of sharing rules under the Quotation object. and I own some of the records. I am admin i have access for all objects. If i want see my own records and all user records also how can i get it..?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo, got it. My Profile is cloned from System Admin, I have all Object access but i am not system admin. Thanks.